# Remote Debugging Fail - No suitable logon session

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, remote-debugging

Receive this error message:

`Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging.`

`Unable to start program "D:\xxx.exe".`

`There appears to be no suitable logon session on the server. Please verify that you are logged on to the server through Terminal Services or that someone is logged into the server locally.`

This is the 1st time i encounter this error message after 4-5 years of using remote debugging. It is a standalone windows application.
Development PC: WinXP SP2, VS.Net 2003.
Deployment PC: WinXP SP2

Has anyone encountered similar problem before? Which configuration could have gone wrong thus contributing to this error message?

p/s: *the end of the message said "... **someone** is logged into the server locally." However, not many search result returns if i google that phrase.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the deployment PC needs a firewall setting to allow control by the development PC?

Comment: I have run the DebuggerFirewall.hta & it creates exception in the firewall setting to allow remote debugging to work. 
I have also turned off the firewall in the deployment PC. The same error message still appears.